# GraphQL-java with Spring - resolvers vd datafetcher

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

There's total mess with GraphQL and Java (Spring). There are multiple projects, and multiple examples, but totally inconsistent.

What I understand Spring Boot should gives is OOTB working solution, and (to some extent) it works like this. Project which gives you such experience is on Github https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart. Especially https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot gives you possibility to create schema, make resolver and everything else is done automatically.

Problem is when you try to replace resolver - which seems like very simply datafetcher - with custom datafetcher. As I know there's no possibility to make asynchronous resolver, or batched resolver - you have to make datafetcher.

To make custom datafetchers one needs to make custom wiring etc, replacing spring-boot solution, or using it somehow (how?). There's no single point of true, how to do that properly. I even found that BatchedDataFetcher are deprecated(!) before they even get a good Spring Boot support/example (see: [GraphQL Java: Using @Batched DataFetcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041371/graphql-java-using-batched-datafetcher))

Because of that I even don't know where to look for solution. What I would welcome to see is to have an example which has:

- Spring Boot support
- asynchronous/parallel datafetcher
- batched datafetcher
- connecting multiple services with GraphQL endpoints (maybe out of scope)
- paging/filtering

Answer (score 6):

> Anyway, the answer is: use graphql-java-kickstart projects, as those
>   from https://www.graphql-java.com/ are outdated. This fact is very
>   misleading and should be stated somewhere.

Not really. `graphql-java` is only `GraphQL` java implementation that I know so far. It defines `DataFetcher`. It is the core library while other projects that you find such as `java-kickstart` (or to be more precise its `graphql-java-tool`) is built on top of the `graphql-java` and it defines its own implementation of the `DataFetcher` which is called `Resolver`.

In the end , the `Resolver` is just a `DataFetcher`.

You can find more related information about these two projects in this [blog post](https://www.graphql-java.com/blog/moving-projects/).

So if you want to have the most flexibility when building the GraphQL server , use `graphql-java` . On the other hand , if you like the opinionated way that is used by `graphql-java-tool` , uses it.

Comment: Tools project has also some Spring examples which are quite old. As I use Spring, it was very hard to understand, why Kickstarter libraries doesn't play with it. The fact that graphql-java promotes old examples on their web pages, and don't tell anything about Kickstarter project, is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

My question was caused by 2 different frameworks which works with graphql-java. Few days later I know that days of datafetchers are gone (which is promoted on https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/).

Now, if you want to go simply, you can make resolvers and you're done: https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart
If you want go deeper, you should make dataloaders: https://github.com/graphql-java/java-dataloader

Anyway, the answer is: use graphql-java-kickstart projects, as those from https://www.graphql-java.com/ are outdated. This fact is very misleading and should be stated somewhere.

Comment: This is good info, but did you ever find good examples? I’m also somewhat lost about what the current ‘best practice’ for batching requests, n+1, etc is within the Java GraphQL ecosystem.